# Rotation view for std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vectors, circular-list

I have this view class for constant time rotations of a **`std::vector`**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
class vector_view {

public:
    vector_view(std::vector<T>& vec) : vec{&vec}, offset{0} {}
    const T& operator[](int index) const {
        return (*vec)[(index + offset) % vec->size()];
    }

    T& operator[](int index) {
        return (*vec)[(index + offset) % vec->size()];
    }

    void rotate(int rotation_length) {
        offset = (offset + vec->size() - rotation_length) % vec->size();
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, vector_view<T>& view) {
        os << "[";
        std::string separator = "";

        for (int index = 0; index < view.vec->size(); ++index)
        {
            os << separator << view[index];
            separator = ", ";
        }

        return os << "]";
    }

private:
    std::vector<T>* vec;
    int offset;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<char> v{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};
    vector_view<char> view{v};

    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << view << std::endl;
        view.rotate(1);
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << view << std::endl;
        view.rotate(-1);
    }
}
```

The demo output is:

> ```
> [a, b, c, d, e]
> [e, a, b, c, d]
> [d, e, a, b, c]
> [c, d, e, a, b]
> [b, c, d, e, a]
>
> [a, b, c, d, e]
> [b, c, d, e, a]
> [c, d, e, a, b]
> [d, e, a, b, c]
> [e, a, b, c, d]
> ```

Since I am still in the process of learning modern C++, please tell me anything I could improve here; such as:

- Naming,
- coding conventions,
- API,
- ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want your vector elements to be modifiable through this view, as `vec` is non-const.

You store a pointer to the underlying vector, but never test it isn't null.  I think it would be better to have it as a reference member.

If you want your view to be as usable as the standard vector, you'll want to provide iterators, and `begin()` and `end()` to obtain them.  You may also want implement `front()`, `back()` and `at()`.  Methods such as `size()`, `reserve`, `capacity` etc. can simply forward to the contained vector.

---

Like `std::vector`, you should override `operator[]` on const:

```
const T& operator[](int index) const {
    return (*vec)[(index + offset) % vec->size()];
}

T& operator[](int index) {
    return (*vec)[(index + offset) % vec->size()];
}
```

---

Once we've implemented `size()` or `begin()`/`end()`, the streaming operator `<<` uses only the public interface, so it no longer needs to be `friend`.

Its loop compares (signed) `int` against (unsigned) `size_t` (g++ warns about this with `-Wall`).  Prefer to avoid implicit promotions, so declare `i` as `size_type` to match `size()`.  If you're pedantic, that should be `vector_view<T>::size_type`, which you'll forward from `std::vector<T>`.  My code below avoids that entirely, by using iterators.

---

Beware the gotcha when `T` is `bool`.  The only thing preventing your code  working on `vector<bool>` is:

```
T& operator[](int index);
```

If you return a `std::vector<T>::reference` instead, that will do the right thing there.  (`std::vector<bool>::reference` is a proxy object, not a `bool&`).

### My modified class:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
class vector_view {
    using vector_type = std::vector<T>;

public:
    using value_type = typename vector_type::value_type;
    using allocator_type = typename vector_type::allocator_type;
    using size_type = typename vector_type::size_type;
    using difference_type = typename vector_type::difference_type;
    using reference = typename vector_type::reference;
    using const_reference = typename vector_type::const_reference;
    using pointer = typename vector_type::pointer;
    using const_pointer = typename vector_type::const_pointer;

    // Iterators: I've implemented little more than the minimum to
    // make the test program work.  You could expand this, and also
    // provide a specialization of std::iterator_traits<> for each
    // one.
    struct iterator {
        vector_view& v;
        size_type i;
        iterator& operator++() { ++i; return *this;}
        iterator& operator-- () { --i; return *this;}
        reference operator*() const { return v[i]; }
        bool operator!=(const iterator other) const
            { return &v != &other.v || i != other.i;  }
    };

    struct const_iterator {
        const vector_view& v;
        size_type i;
        const_iterator& operator++() { ++i; return *this;}
        const_iterator& operator-- () { --i; return *this;}
        const_reference operator*() const { return v[i]; }
        bool operator!=(const const_iterator other) const
            { return &v != &other.v || i != other.i;  }
    };

    using reverse_iterator = std::reverse_iterator<iterator>;
    using const_reverse_iterator = std::reverse_iterator<const_iterator>;

    explicit vector_view(vector_type& vec, int offset = 0)
        : vec{vec},
          offset{offset}
    {}

    const reference operator[](size_type index) const {
        return vec[(index + offset) % vec.size()];
    }

    reference operator[](size_type index) {
        return vec[(index + offset) % vec.size()];
    }

    void rotate(int rotation_length) {
        auto size = vec.size();
        offset = (offset + size - rotation_length) % size;
    }

    void set_rotation(int rotation_length) {
        offset = rotation_length % vec.size();
    }

    int rotation() const {
        return offset;
    }

    // Iterators
    iterator begin() {
        return iterator{*this, 0};
    }
    const_iterator begin() const {
        return const_iterator{*this, 0};
    }
    const_iterator cbegin() const {
        return begin();
    }
    iterator end() {
        return iterator{*this, size()};
    }
    const_iterator end() const {
        return const_iterator{*this, size()};
    }
    const_iterator cend() const {
        return end();
    }
    // You may wish to implement rbegin/rend and crbegin/crend

    bool empty() const { return vec.empty(); }
    size_type size() const { return vec.size(); }

    // You may also want:
    // reserve(), capacity()
    // clear(), insert(), emplace(), erase(), ..., etc.

private:
    vector_type& vec;
    int offset;
};
```

```
// Consider implementing operator==(), operator<() and other
// comparisons (as non-member functions, probably).  You could
// probably use std::mismatch() for that.
```

```
// Printing: greatly simplified using range-based `for`.
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const vector_view<T>& view) {
    os << "[";

    std::string separator = "";
    for (auto element: view) {
        os << separator << element;
        separator = ", ";
    }

    return os << "]";
}
```

```
// Test program: exercises both `normal` and boolean vectors.
int main() {
    std::vector<char> v{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};
    vector_view<char> view{v};

    for (size_t i = 0; i < view.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << view << std::endl;
        view.rotate(1);
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < view.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << view << std::endl;
        view.rotate(-1);
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::vector<bool> bvec{{false, true, true, false, false}};
    auto bview = vector_view<bool>{bvec};

    for (size_t i = 0; i < bview.size(); ++i) {
        bview.set_rotation(i);
        std::cout << bview << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks pretty nice already. Here are some minor nits

1. You can declare `vec` const in the constructor and add explicit so that there is no other possible constructor.
2. I personally dislike using int for variables that are strict non negative, but this is purely opinion based.
3. You can use range based loops in your implementation

   ```
   for (auto &elem : *vec)
   ```
4. You should write a getOffset function

Comment: Note that 3 does not apply: I need to be able to iterate the rotation of the vector and not the vector itself.